# Excel: VLookUp solves a potential Nested IF problem

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I manually enter numbers on one cell according to text values in the cell adjacent to it. Is there a way to use the IF function to help me manage this? The text is automatically generated with a report but I put the numbers in manually in Excel.

Example of my weekly boredom below:

```
number    Text in Cell
3         Order A
3         Order A 
1         Order C
2         Order B
3         Order A
1         Order C
2         Order B
2         Order B
```

HELP! My eyes and soul hurt each time I need to do this.
Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use VLOOKUP instead

In another sheet have a table of the text values and their corresponding numbers, ordered by the lookup value (that bit is important!):

```
Order A          3
Order B          2
Order C          1
```

You can then use VLOOKUP(column_with_generated_text, lookup_table, 2)

The 2 means it will return the 2nd column value from the lookup table, i.e. the number.

This way, if you get more text/number pairs to be added you need only add them to the lookup and not have to change complex IF statements each time.

EDIT: This is what I did on my test XLS...

Sheet 1:- 2 columns, A1:B5:

```
Commissioned-1st activity   5
Commissioned-2nd activity   4
First response - write     1
Workplan to write           2
Workplan-company to agree   3
```

I then defined a Named Range for A1:B5 as "lookup" (without quotes)

Sheet 2:- Column A1:A5:

```
First response - write
Workplan to write
Workplan-company to agree
Commissioned-2nd activity
Commissioned-1st activity
```

Then in column B1:B5 the formulas:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,lookup,2,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP(A2,lookup,2,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP(A3,lookup,2,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP(A4,lookup,2,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP(A5,lookup,2,FALSE)
```

This gives me a column B1:B5 of:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: They don't need to be sorted if you add the "FALSE" parameter at the end.  Which would instead make the formula "VLOOKUP(column_with_generated_text, lookup_table, 2, FALSE)".  This means that it searches for an exact match, rather than just stopping on what it considers 'closest'.

Comment: Ah, thanks Margaret - I've learnt something new as well!

Comment: I've written the formula and, well it gives me room for thought. It isn't doing what i thought it would. My Generated text is in Column A and my values are in Column B. My generated text is in Alphabetical order, which means my Values are not: 5, 4, 1, 2, 3. When I drag the formula down in to the cells below it just starts making it up as it goes along. Any ideas? And after 4th cell (there are 5 rows in my table) I get the #Value error.

Comment: I tried adding false and the results are the same. The text has 'hyphens' in it; does this cause a problem?

Comment: try giving the lookup table a Named Range and using this in the VLOOKUP formula

Comment: Tried. Still not working. The error seems to be coming from my Lookup_Value. This is my text column. I have 5 entries: Commissioned-1st activity (Value=5); Commissioned-2nd activity(4); First response - write(1); Workplan to write(2)
Workplan-company to agree(3). Does anything jump out as causing problems?

Comment: I've just set this up as a test and all works fine... is there any way I can send you my test xls so you can take a look?

Comment: I've edited my answer with steps to generate my test xls - hopefully it makes sense(!) and you can follow it to apply to yours.

Comment: Thanks Shevek: My problem was that I wasn't asking it to refer to the the Cell reference within the list I- i asked it to look at the LookUp table itself. Your step 3 showed me the error on my ways. Wonderful. I now understand VLookUp a lot better.

Comment: Excellent! Vlookups can save a lot of time - its something I use a lot